# php - utf8 encoding the text twice. Will it have any negative effect?

Tags: php, mysql, utf-8, character-encoding

MySQL Database returns `utf8` encoded text. Basically, I used `PDO` attribute `MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND` and passed:

```
SET CHARACTER SET utf8
```

It returns `utf8` encoded text. But some text in the database is plain `utf8`, something like `&alum;` are returned as is.

So I need to call `utf8_encode` again in php to get the actual `utf8` char. Its working fine.

I would like to know, if it will have any negative effect encoding the text twice or it does not affect anything other than encoding the non-encoded text like above?

Thanks!

**Edit:**

I am using the following code to get the right characters:

```
 $val = utf8_encode(addslashes(html_entity_decode(strip_tags($val))));
```

So what it does is convert the following text from:

```
<font color=\"#222222\" face=\"arial, sans-serif\" size=\"2\"> Test Event  &nbsp; &nbsp;</font><span style=\"color: rgb(34, 34, 34); font-family: arial, sans-serif; font-size: 13px;\">Pers&ouml;nlichkeit Universit&auml;t&quot;</span>
```

(This text is coming from the database, after calling the `SET CHARACTER SET utf8`)

to:

```
Test Event Persönlichkeit Universität\"
```

Comment: I can't understand a word of your question. For some reason, everybody seems to think that `utf8_encode()` is a magic function that automatically fixes any encoding issue ever. It isn't, is just converts from ISO-8859-1 to UTF-8. `&alum;` is an HTML entity. All those chars (&-a-l-u-m;) are the same in ISO-8859-1 and UTF-8 so `utf8_encode()` does absolutely nothing. Which is not that bad—in other cases it'll just corrupt your data.

Comment: Thats right. I think I need to be more detailed there. I am going to edit the question

Comment: No. I just wanted to know if there will be any negative effect on utf8 encoding the text twice. Plain and simple.

Comment: Running it once will already corrupt your data, so running it twice will corrupt it even more. Test with e.g. an € symbol.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`&auml;` is a html entity that probably shouldn't have made it to your database in the first place. It has nothing to do with UTF-8.

If you call `utf8_encode` on `"&auml;"` nothing will happen as the encoding is the same for ISO-8859-1 and UTF-8. You will see the character it represents in browser because it is interpreted as html.

You should never, as a normal web app developer, call `utf8_encode`. You don't actually need ISO-8859-1 to UTF-8 conversion, firstly because browsers and MySQL do not support it. They alias Latin1 and ISO-8859-1 to Windows-1252 for compatibility. Secondly, you can cause browsers and database to send their data in UTF-8 so it is already UTF-8 and no conversion is necessary.

You shouldn't convert to html entities either - it is unnecessary because UTF-8 can represent all characters.

The data in database should not have any concern about html - the data there should be canonical authorative as-is representation of data. Right now there is confusion whether the data is actually literally meant to be `&auml;` or `ä` which causes problems like this:

[image]

Image from [TheDailyWTF](http://thedailywtf.com/Articles/Rock-amp8216n-Bowl-Champion.aspx)